# Too many independent clauses?

Tags: grammaticality, clauses, subordinate-clauses, style

Can I have thoughts on this sentence? I worry that the clauses are too many or that the positioning of 'would' is awkward.

> On other other hand, Common Law, which at this point has infiltrated
>   the scene, would, as we can gather from from Littleton’s writing, deem
>   the contract against the law and therefore void.

Comment: Nice sentence! I don't see grammatical mistakes though. But that's a hunch, not an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Not being fully aware of your intention with the sentence (there are some parts which are ambiguous), I agree that it is grammatical. (You do have a few words that repeat , you could re-order the clauses to flow better, and there are synonyms that you could use to shorten parts of it.) However, the main reason why you may be having a problem with it is because of how it "looks". The only punctuation that you use, other than a period, is the comma.

Feel free to avail yourself of the more than a dozen of other marks that you may use to make your sentence easier to read. For example:

From this:

> *"On other **other** hand, Common Law, which at this point has infiltrated the scene, would, as we can gather from **from** Littleton’s writing, deem the contract against the law and therefore void."*

To this:

> "On other hand, Common Law ***(which at this point has infiltrated the scene)*** would, as we can gather from Littleton’s writing, deem the contract against the law and therefore void."

Or this:

> ***"On other hand, we can gather from Littleton’s writing that Common Law (which at this point has infiltrated the scene) would deem the contract unlawful and therefore void."***

Hope this helps.